# Unable to install my own application

Tags: android

I've developed android app, and via the eclipse debugging mode the apk installs and works successfully.
but when I'm sending my unsigned APK to a friend, he gets after installation - Application Not Installed - without any error.

What can it be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot install an unsigned APK. It can be signed by the debug signing key (what happens by default when you build) or signed with a production signing key, but it has to be signed.